# How can I programmatically alter Webform "To Email Address"?

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to change email addresses based on postal codes entered by users.
My code looks like below.

```
function my_webform_tracker_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) {
  $node_id = (int)$renderable['#node']->nid;
  if ($node_id == 257) {
    $postal_code = (int)$renderable['#submission']->data[5][0];
    if($postal_code >= 14000 && $postal_code <= 14990) {
      $renderable['#email'][email] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
      $renderable['#node']->webform['emails'][1]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
      $renderable['#node']->webform['emails'][2]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
      //print "<pre>"; print_r($renderable); exit;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a lot but the email id seems to be not changed. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more apt place to alter the destination email would be [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) where Drupal lets you alter an email before sending it out. The webform module includes all the submission data in the `$message['params']['submission']` object.

You can do something like this in your module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {

  //Catch Webform submissions when we have a valid postal code
  if($message['id'] == 'webform_submission') {
    $postal_code_component = 5;
    if(isset($message['params']['submission']->data[$postal_code_component][0])) {
      $postal_code = (int) $message['params']['submission']->data[$postal_code_component][0];

      //Find right addressee to switch to
      if(0 <= $postal_code && $postal_code <= 13999 ) { 
        $message['to'] = 'addressee.1@example.com'; 
      } elseif(14000 <= $postal_code && $postal_code <= 14990) { //Etc...
        $message['to'] = 'addressee.2@example.com';
      } else { //Catchall
        $message['to'] = 'addressee.3@example.com';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, actually I was using wrong hook to do the task. The right on would be "hook_webform_submission_presave". So my code will look like,

```
    function my_webform_tracker_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
      $postal_code = (int)$renderable['#submission']->data[5][0];
      if($postal_code >= 14000 && $postal_code <= 14990) {
        $node->webform['emails'][1]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";
        $node->webform['emails'][2]['email'] = "thisemailid@mydomain.com";      
      }
    }
```

Thank You everyone for help!!